Shell script to run command and show output in notification box
I have command line utility that generates text strings, by running a command within the directory:
./Utility -P

it prints output on terminal. How to make a shell script showing the generated string in the Info dialog box, where the output can be selected by mouse and copied. So I need send information from a shell script to a GUI desktop environment.
I mean launch a shell scipt by double click on it, so there is no longer needs to open terminal every time and write command.
EDIT: working example
#!/bin/bash
output="$( ./Utility -P )"
zenity --info  --text "${output}" --icon-name=info --title "Daily test" --width=300 --height=80


You could try zenity.

You mean redirect output, like zenity --notification --window-icon=info --text="$MESSAGE"?

This will capture standard output from this sub shell and save it to an environment variable named output. You can call it any other name.
output="$( ./Utility -P )"
zenity --info --text "${output}" --title "Utility finished"

There are alternative tools such as yad (a fork of zenity iirc), or even a way to use your desktop's notification utility (using dbus) if you have one. Assuming you have xfce4-notification-daemon or some other daemon consuming that notification stuff:
notify-send --icon /opt/icons/Utility.png -- "Utility finished" "${output}"

Where the first string will go to the "title" of the notification, and the second string will be the "body" of the notification.
EDIT: or even just xmessage "${output}" if you like minimal dependencies, though that assumes ${output} doesn't match one of the options supported by xmessage. Alternatively: ./Utility -P | xmessage -file - which doesn't have the problem.

I saved above example as shell script test.sh: #!/bin/bash output="$( ./Utility -P )" zenity --info --text "${output}" --title "test" but it opens in Mousepad.

To make a script executable, you have to mark the file as such. chmod +x ./test.sh which changes the mode to add executable flag for the owning user, owning usergroup, and other users. Depending on how you're trying to run the script, it might only ever want to open in a text editor, but after +x it might ask you if you are certain you want to run it.

Of course, I already gave script permission to run as a program, but in Properties was specified "Open with Mousepad", I changed to "Terminal Emulator" and it works.
